# Go High Level - Create a summary of the information submitted in the 3 previous pages of a form

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to display a summary of the data submitted by a user so they can edit or change the information if it's needed. The forms were builded in Go High Level, so I'm just adding a JS script to the page were is each one of the forms to collect the data. I used inspect to get the fields IDs but they don't have any, so I used the name tag.

Here is the code:

Form page 1:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const nextButton = document.querySelector('button[type="button"]');
    const firstForm = document.getElementById("form-RNThrQSFOF");

    nextButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        const address = encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('[name="address"]').value);
        const homeSize = encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('[name="m4qPNC8AsUoECkoLubyx"]').value);
        const pets = encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('[name="x99Laa44rseuNoF4kLjF"]').value);

        // Store data in sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem("address", address);
        sessionStorage.setItem("m4qPNC8AsUoECkoLubyx", homeSize);
        sessionStorage.setItem("x99Laa44rseuNoF4kLjF", pets);

        // Navigate to the second form page
        window.location.href = "https://app.gohighlevel.com/v2/preview/MNSlTy4KrAdcx9kcxYPk";
    });
});
</script>
```

Form page 2:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const submitButton = document.querySelector('button[type="button"]');
    const secondForm = document.getElementById("#form-mBYK30hyM3");

    // Pre-fill form fields using data from sessionStorage
    document.getElementById("serviceType").value = decodeURIComponent(sessionStorage.getItem("serviceType")) || "";
    document.getElementById("frequency").value = decodeURIComponent(sessionStorage.getItem("frequency")) || "";
    document.getElementById("lastDeepClean").value = decodeURIComponent(sessionStorage.getItem("lastDeepClean")) || "";
    document.getElementById("extras").value = decodeURIComponent(sessionStorage.getItem("extras")) || "";
    document.getElementById("needBy").value = decodeURIComponent(sessionStorage.getItem("needBy")) || "";

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        // Gather additional data from form fields
        const serviceType = encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('[name="IzpbXJiSDYeispp4N21S"]').value);
        const frequency = encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('[name="5Q7ElqqUIG1gH5mGTz5V"]').value);
        const lastDeepClean = encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('[name="Lk7UNY3FrFQ0CjFAUdKL"]').value);
        const extras = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Blinds_ZBpBtAIrq0dO1UEbmYGm_0_4g1fmuwqhwq").value);
        const needBy = encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('[name="d8FrRRXd7e0mFIocnORo"]').value);

        // Store additional data in sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem("IzpbXJiSDYeispp4N21S", serviceType);
        sessionStorage.setItem("5Q7ElqqUIG1gH5mGTz5V", frequency);
        sessionStorage.setItem("Lk7UNY3FrFQ0CjFAUdKL", lastDeepClean);
        sessionStorage.setItem("Blinds_ZBpBtAIrq0dO1UEbmYGm_0_4g1fmuwqhwq", extras);
        sessionStorage.setItem("d8FrRRXd7e0mFIocnORo", needBy);

        // Navigate to the summary page
        window.location.href = "https://app.gohighlevel.com/v2/preview/AFrD1F0q5VGW6PmVDJVG";
    });
});
```

Form page 3:

It a video submission. I don't have code for this part.

Form page 4 (Summary)

```
<style>
    #summary-container{
        color: #000000;
        font-family: "Inter", Sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
        background-color: #EDEDED;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-left: 8%;
        margin-right: 8%;
        align-content: center;
    }
</style>
<div id="summary-container">
  <div>

    <li><strong>Address:</strong> <span name="address"></span></li>
    <li><strong>Home size:</strong> <span name="m4qPNC8AsUoECkoLubyx"></span></li>
    <li><strong>Pets:</strong> <span name="x99Laa44rseuNoF4kLjF"></span></li>
    <li><strong>Service Type:</strong> <span name="IzpbXJiSDYeispp4N21S"></span></li>
    <li><strong>Frequency:</strong> <span name="5Q7ElqqUIG1gH5mGTz5V"></span></li>
    <li><strong>Last Deep Clean:</strong> <span name="Lk7UNY3FrFQ0CjFAUdKL"></span></li>
    <li><strong>Extras:</strong> <span name="Blinds_ZBpBtAIrq0dO1UEbmYGm_0_4g1fmuwqhwq"></span></li>
    <li><strong>Need By:</strong> <span name="d8FrRRXd7e0mFIocnORo"></span></li>
    <video class="custom-file-upload" controls="">
      <source id="summaryVideoSource" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Retrieve data from sessionStorage
  const address = decodeURIComponent(sessionStorage.getItem("address"));
  const homeSize = decodeURIComponent(sessionStorage.getItem("m4qPNC8AsUoECkoLubyx"));
  const pets = decodeURIComponent(sessionStorage.getItem("x99Laa44rseuNoF4kLjF"));
  const serviceType = decodeURIComponent(sessionStorage.getItem("serviceType"));
  const frequency = decodeURIComponent(sessionStorage.getItem("5Q7ElqqUIG1gH5mGTz5V"));
  const lastDeepClean = decodeURIComponent(sessionStorage.getItem("lastDeepClean"));
  const extras = decodeURIComponent(sessionStorage.getItem("extras"));
  const needBy = decodeURIComponent(sessionStorage.getItem("d8FrRRXd7e0mFIocnORo"));
  const videoUrl = sessionStorage.getItem("videoUrl"); // URL of the submitted video

  // Populate placeholders using the name attributes
  document.querySelector('[name="address"]').textContent = address;
  document.querySelector('[name="m4qPNC8AsUoECkoLubyx"]').textContent = homeSize;
  document.querySelector('[name="x99Laa44rseuNoF4kLjF"]').textContent = pets;
  document.querySelector('[name="IzpbXJiSDYeispp4N21S"]').textContent = serviceType;
  document.querySelector('[name="5Q7ElqqUIG1gH5mGTz5V"]').textContent = frequency;
  document.querySelector('[name="Lk7UNY3FrFQ0CjFAUdKL"]').textContent = lastDeepClean;
  document.querySelector('[name="Blinds_ZBpBtAIrq0dO1UEbmYGm_0_4g1fmuwqhwq"]').textContent = extras;
  document.querySelector('[name="d8FrRRXd7e0mFIocnORo"]').textContent = needBy;

  const videoElement = document.querySelector('.custom-file-upload'); // Select the video element using the class name

  if (videoElement) {
    const videoSource = document.createElement('source');
    videoSource.src = videoUrl;
    videoSource.type = 'video/mp4';
    videoElement.appendChild(videoSource);
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, _specific_ question. Don't add tags.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You should use a good editor or run your page through a validator. List items must be children of a list. Also, `name` is an _attribute_, not a tag.